# Improve Oracle Query Structure

Tags: sql, oracle

My query takes about 2 minutes to execute, any suggestions on how to improve the query in order to reduce this 2 minute wait time.

My Query:

```
SELECT
 PRICE, VOLUME, BLOCK
FROM 
 owner.table
WHERE
 basis = 'location_name" AND
 tableSource = 'DetailTable' AND
 type = 'Sales' AND
 contractMonth = '05' AND
 to_char(createDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2016-01-01'
```

Comment: you'd need to provide more info, such as which indexes you have on the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would rewrite the query to look like this:

```
SELECT t.PRICE, t.VOLUME, t.BLOCK
FROM owner.table t
WHERE basis = 'location_name' AND
      tableSource = 'DetailTable' AND
      type = 'Sales' AND
      contractMonth = '05' AND
      createDate >= date '2016-01-01' AND
      createDate < date '2016-01-02';
```

Then, to improve performance, create an index on `(basis, tableSource, type, contractMonth, createDate)`.

You could also add `price`, `volume`, and `block` as the last three columns in the index.  The index would then *cover* the query, meaning that the index has all columns and there is no need to load the original data pages.

Comment: @Michaelpanicci - Please note how Gordon re-wrote the condition on `createDate`. A separate index on `createDate` may be the most helpful, if that condition is the most selective. (However, in order for that index to be available, the column should NOT be wrapped within a function, like `TO_CHAR` - this is why Gordon's re-write is much better.) If you create a composite index like Gordon suggests, make sure the FIRST column in the index is the one that will be the most selective in the table. For example, `type` may be more selective than `basis` if there are only 3 locations vs 14 types.

Comment: @mathguy - I only have read access to the database, indexing is a process that would require me to modify the actual database?

Comment: @Michaelpanicci - First see if indexes exist already. Then, especially if there is already an index on `createDate`, see if the code modification proposed by Gordon is enough to speed up your query to an acceptable execution time (it may!) If that doesn't help, discuss with your DBA; you will not be able to add indexes with only read access. If they push back, there's a fight between the DBA and the consumers who need the query to run faster; you are not part of that fight, you are only the messenger.

Answer (score 0):

Check your indexes and make sure that your index columns type is same type your values. For example; is contractMonth column number or varchar etc. Because if you want to use your index, each side in equation must be same type. Also, check your last analyzed date for true optimization based on actual histograms.